# Pasting data from text file to excel using VB 2010 express

Tags: vb.net, excel

This may sound very easy but I am a newbie in vb programming. I have a text file with 11 rows, 2 columns separated by 39 spaces between them. Now I'm trying to read this file, copy it & paste into an excel sheet. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim oExcel As Object
        Dim oBook As Object
        Dim oRow As Int16 = 0

        oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add

        'Read input .txt file line-by-line, Copy to Clipboard & Paste to Excel

        Using rdr As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\Temp\ONI.txt")
            Do While rdr.Peek() >= 0
                Dim InputLine As String = rdr.ReadLine
                oRow = oRow + 1
                System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetDataObject (InputLine)
                oBook.Worksheets(1).Range("A" + oRow.ToString).Select()
                oBook.Worksheets(1).Paste()
            Loop
            rdr.Close()
        End Using

        oExcel.Visible = True
        'oExcel.SaveAs("C\Temp\test.xls")
        oBook = Nothing
        oExcel.Quit()
        oExcel = Nothing
    End Sub

End Class
```

This is working to the extent that an excel workbook is opened & the data is getting pasted in A1 to A11 i.e the rows are 11 (which is ok) but the column is only 1 (it should be in columns A & B). I know this is very easy, please guide me.

Also the code stops at the "Save as" line (which I have commented). When run it shows error `Public member 'SaveAs' on type 'ApplicationClass' not found.`

Comment: For SaveAs, see this link:

http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/09/12/saving-and-closing-the-excel-file-savesave-as-method/

Regarding the pasting, the text will be pasted in Col A. You will have to use `Text To Columns` to separate that data For that see this link 

http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/06/29/excel-text-to-columns-from-vb-net/

Comment: Thanks Siddharth ! Both problems resolved. You were a genuine help guiding me to your blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing `oBook.SaveAs(...)`, you are not saving the `Excel.Application`, just the workbook.

For importing text, why not just use the `Workbooks.OpenText` method?  With some tweaking this should allow you to open the delimited files in the desired format.  This saves yout he hassle of trying to also do text-to-columns after importing it, and the nasty hassle of having to work with the clipboard.

E.g., this opens a text file in an Excel workbook, treats spaces as the delimiter, consecutive delimiters as one, so it should split your columns correctly.

```
Sub OpenTextFile()
Dim wbText As Workbook
Dim sFName As String ' file name & path'

sFName = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=sFName _
    , Origin:=437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:= _
    xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False _
    , Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Here is the test file I used:

[image: Text file with consecutive delimiters]

And here is the output, properly in 2 columns:

[image: Excel can open the text delimited file]