# Stop CSV import into Excel from converting text to time

Tags: excel, csv

I have a CSV file that contains headers in the format of "1 A", "2 A", "3 A", etc. When I import the file they get converted to 1:00 AM, 2:00 AM, 3:00 AM and so on.

What can I do to prevent this? Do I have to change the format of the text in some way so that Excel will leave it as is? If so what do I need to add?

Comment: If they are qualified with a double quote, e.g., `"1 A"`, then I would expect CSV to interpret them as Text, not time.

Comment: If you're importing (not just loading the csv) then you should be able to specify the datatype of each column. Type:General will try to guess what it is, usually badly :)

Comment: If you control the generation of the CSV too then quoting your strings as @DavidZemens suggests would also be a good idea!

Comment: See also how to use the `Workbooks.OpenText` method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16065972/1467082 although this may not be what you're after, if you **only** want to ignore the data type in the header row.

Comment: Unfortunately the user is just loading the CSV file so the wizard is not an option. I will have to modify the code that creates the CSV file to add "" around the header columns.

Comment: Well that didn't work either. Excel still treats "1 A" as time. I am going to have to adjust the headers to remove the space so that it becomes "1A" instead.

Comment: Well, removing the space was the answer. It seems Excel interprets the string "1 A" as a time/date instead of text even though the value is inside quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with David, enclosing values in double quotes should make Excel treat column Values as text, but with a Column Header - who knows.

One possible solution:
During the import wizard you might try changing the value for "Start import at row" =2, and then ensuring the "Column data format" is Text. Then you can manually enter the column header names.

From: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-import-wizard-HP010102244.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same problem and I get rid off by following funda

First Convert in into UTF - 8

If user is using windows add BOM(Byte Order Mark)

If user using MAC or other OS (Remove BOM)

```
var is_Mac = navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') >= 0;
if (is_Mac) {
    var csvData = csv;
}
else {
    var BOM = "\uFEFF";
    var csvData = BOM + csv;
}
var csvFile = new Blob([csvData], { type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8" });
var urlHref = URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);
```

Hope this will resolve your issue